# Getting to the end of a function

Tags: c++

I want to read a text file wich contains C++ code. I want to add some code at the end of the function. The problem is that I don't really know how to get to the end of the function, because there can be if statements and strings and whatever containing "}". So how should I do this? Regex?

Comment: You'll need to essentially write a C++ parser.

Comment: For the general case, this is in no way a simple objective. You may be able to get something to work for specific cases, but the only way to really make this work is to property and correctly pre-process and parse the C++ code.

Comment: Your question (as stated) suggests there is only one function in the file, and if the file with the single function compiles, you know the braces are balanced.  Thus, you could simply load the file into a std::string, then use rfind().  The algorithm to find the mate for any given brace in the code is also straight forward.  (I prefer recursion.)

Comment: Yeah, there is not going to be just one function... I tink a parser will do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use some tools like Lex and YACC, I Think Lex is enough for your requirement.
Here you can find lex and it's tutorial.
[Lex Tutorial](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/lex/)